# How to make TypeScript 2 to find node modules?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546860/require-nodejs-child-process-with-typescript-systemjs-and-electron) answer, but it didn't solve my problem.

I'm just learning TypeScript.

What I'm doing is as simple as this:

```
import * as child from 'child_process';
```

Which triggers this error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
db\installDB.ts (1,24): Cannot find module 'child_process'. (2307)
```

What I thought is: It's not finding 'child_process' because I have no typings for it, so I added `@types/node` on the hope it would now find it. It didn't.

What is the problem?

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./db/**/*",
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What type of module is `child_process`? The simplest way to import an ambient module is to use the shorthand described in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
import child = require('child_process');
```

This is a commonjs style import, used for nodejs modules, instead of the current ES6-style import you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have webpack.config.js**

Add following array to `devConfig` and `prodConfig` in your `webpack.config.json`

```
 externals: [
(function () {
    var IGNORES = ["fs","child_process","electron","path","assert","cluster","crypto","dns","domain","events","http","https","net","os","process","punycode","querystring","readline","repl","stream","string_decoder","tls","tty","dgram","url","util","v8","vm","zlib"];
    return function (context, request, callback) {
        if (IGNORES.indexOf(request) >= 0) {
            return callback(null, "require('" + request + "')");
        }
        return callback();
    };
})()
],
```

This will ignore modules listed in `IGNORES` array.

Then, in your 'Typescript' file.

```
declare var require:any;
...
...
var exec = require('child_process');
```

If you don't have **webpack.config** and your project is working on webpack. You can find it in "node_modules/app_scripts/config". Copy webpack.config from that path and save it in config folder at the root of your project and paste the following code to your `package.json`

```
"config": {
   "ionic_bundler": "webpack",
   "ionic_webpack": "./config/webpack.config.js"
 },
```

**If you have `SystemJS`**

Add following code to system.config.js

```
 System.config({
  map: {
    'child_process': '@node/child_process'
  }
});
```