# Ionic 3 - use electron's 'child_process'

Tags: typescript, types, electron, ionic3, child-process

I am building a desktop application in which i want to open external application from my app. I'm using electron's `child_process` for performing this operation. But I'm stuck in how to import `child_process` on TypeScript file.

I tried to use `require('child_process').exec` and `System.import('child_process').exec` but it is throwing error "Can't find module 'child_process'.

But when i use it on `index.html` in `<script>` it works properly!

I got this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36549645/7088848). But it is working with SystemJS. But my project is not configured with SystemJS.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's pretty likely that you actually want the `exec` or `spawn` from the `child_process` module. That'd look more like this `const {exec} = require('child_process');`

Comment: Thanks for concern @ChrisRiebschlager . I got the solution described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

Need to add following array in `webpack.config.js`.

```
 externals: [
(function () {
    var IGNORES = ["fs","child_process","electron","path","assert","cluster","crypto","dns","domain","events","http","https","net","os","process","punycode","querystring","readline","repl","stream","string_decoder","tls","tty","dgram","url","util","v8","vm","zlib"];
    return function (context, request, callback) {
        if (IGNORES.indexOf(request) >= 0) {
            return callback(null, "require('" + request + "')");
        }
        return callback();
    };
})()
],
```

This will tell ionic to ignore modules listed in array `IGNORES`.

Comment: Hello, I'm stuck importing child_process too in an electron + ionic app, but I don't have any webpack.config.js. Somewhere I read that I should use tsconfig.json, but the snippet you post in your solution is not json compliant. Do you have any idea on how to solve that? Should I install webpack in the project?